# Concatenate $matches in Wordpress URL rewrite rule

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a particular URL rewriting using 2 resultats of a regexp in my query vars :

```
add_rewrite_rule('edition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]-$matches[1]', 'top');
```

It does not work, when :

```
add_rewrite_rule('edition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=videos-$matches[1]', 'top');
```

perfectly works, so it seems that I am not concatenating the 2 values correctly, but I can't find the right way.
Does anybody have a clue ?

Comment: According to [this post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/#comment-4554), you code is correct. Did you see the previous post saying "*Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.*"

Comment: Yes, thank you, I flush the rewrite rules on init during dev with flush_rewrite_rules()

Comment: Is there a way to print $matches to ensure $matches[2] is what I expect ?